# How to pre-check and set variable before compiling on Go?

Tags: go, hcl

I'm going to pre-check HCL contents and set it as a variable in `golang`.
i.e. HCL contents should be parsed before compilation and set as a specific variable.

Here is the example.

```
.
├── config.mel
└── main.go
```

The `config.mel` has the following HCL strings.

```
types {
    directory = "string"
    listen = "ipaddr"
}
```

The `main.go` has the following lines:

```
package main

import (
     "github.com/hashicorp/hcl"
)

func main() {
    hcl.Parse(HCL_CONTENTS)
}
```

Is there any method to set `HCL_CONTENTS` variable before compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [go generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to accomplish this, if you can build a command to create the code you want.